# how to pick chars from a string in defined but different sized steps?

Tags: python, string, char, slice

I want to pick chars from a string in two changing steps, lets say the 1st and the 9th char, the 10th and the 19th and so on through the whole string.

What is a fast & pythonic way to do so?

Comment: You'll have to be able to define a pattern of access in order to achieve this. Your example does not exhibit a pattern, as there are 7 elements between the 1st and 9th (not counting the endpoints), and 8 elements between the 10th and 19th... What would the next set be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
>>> sum(zip(string[0::10], string[9::10]), ())
('a', 'j', 'k', 't', 'u', '3')
```

And a 100% lazy evaluation (use izip instead of zip for python 2):

```
>>> from itertools import islice #, izip
>>> string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
>>> it = zip(islice(string, 0, None, 10), islice(string, 9, None, 10))
>>> flat_it = (char for tpl in it for char in tpl)
>>> tuple(flat_it)
('a', 'j', 'k', 't', 'u', '3')
```

Comment: In Python 3 both solutions return no values but a reference to a zip object.

Comment: The `sum` version should return a tuple in both python 2 and 3.

Comment: The list works, sum again returns a zip object...

Comment: Works for me with Python 2.7, 3.2 and 3.4.

Comment: Then this seems to be due to Python 3.3.5 which I'm using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60085/discussion-between-vincent-and-barrios).

Answer (score 1):

For a generic "repeating pattern" solution, you might combine [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) and [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
>>> s='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
#      123456789012345678901234567890123456
#      *       **       **       **       *
#      100000001
#      <pattern><--------- cycle---------->


>>> it=itertools.compress(s, itertools.cycle([1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]))
#                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                                  "pick-up pattern" -- whatever you need
#                                     (1 to keep a char. 0 to ignore)
>>> list(it)
['a', 'i', 'j', 'r', 's', '0', '1', '9']
```

If all your patterns have the same structure as specified in your example (I wouldn't favor this as it is less readable though...):

```
>>> [p[::8] for p in [s[i:i+9] for i in range(0,len(s), 9)]]
#                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                       split string in chunks of 9 chars 
#     ^^^^
#   keep char 0 and 0+8 of each chunk      
['ai', 'jr', 's0', '19']
```

Of course, you might wan to use `join` to combine result items as a whole string:

```
>>> "".join([p[::8] for p in [s[i:i+9] for i in range(0,len(s), 9)]])
'aijrs019'
```

Comment: Also a quite pythonic solution, I think. According to cProfile there is no speed gain over the code using built-in-functions sum & zip. And maybe this one is a little more difficult to read. Anyway, TNX!

Answer (score 0):

How is this? Uses two variables to store steps, increments by 10.

```
step1=0;
step2=8;
str1="This is a basic string to hopefully demonstrate the lines of python code below";
while(len(str1)>step1) :
  print(str1[step1]);
  if(len(str1)>step2): print(str1[step2]);
  step1+=10;
  step2+=10;
```

Outputs:

```
T
a
b
r
n
p
f
m
n
t
e
o

c
d
```

Update: Using List Comprehensions

```
import itertools;

str1="This is a basic string to hopefully demonstrate the lines of python code below";
[print(str1[i]) for i in itertools.chain(range(0,len(str1),10), range(9,len(str1),10))];
```

Comment: As I wrote I need the 1st char first and then the 9th and so on. Besides a while loop would be too slow, I need something faster like a comprehension, mapping etc...

Comment: It does, it just wasn't zero-based (which I fixed). And something faster. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: There, updated using comprehension.

Comment: Looks promising, but output is not quite correct: Tbnf...